# Inconsistent addition with `Number.MAX_VALUE`

Tags: javascript, numbers

In Javascript, `Number.MAX_VALUE` is the biggest value for a number. I got a question that

```
(Number.MAX_VALUE + 123) == Number.MAX_VALUE  //true
(Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE) == Number.MAX_VALUE  //false
```

I can't understand. Can someone explain me?

Comment: floating point arithmetic is like that

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE == Infinity` and
`Number.MAX_VALUE + 123 = Number.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: by the way `(Number.MAX_VALUE+Math.pow(2,969))` is not infinity ... `(Number.MAX_VALUE+Math.pow(2,970))` is - in case you wanted to know the cut-off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, you just increase your number by a really tiny number: 
`123` according to `1.79^308` is nothing. So you **"lost" some precision**: it does not change the number.

In the second one, you exceed the max value, so your number is **not a number anymore**, it is `Infinity`.

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE + 123);
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE);

/* Is (Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE) a number? */
console.log(Number.isInteger(Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are just losing precision (adding a relatively tiny number to another has no effect), while in the second you are overflowing to Infinity.

*Edit:* Think of `Number.MAX_VALUE+123` as an approximation: it's like trying to sum `1 + 0.000000000000000000000001`.... you still get `1` because numbers only have a finite precision